# How to read Json and pass its properties to page method that returns promise using protractor

Tags: json, for-loop, protractor, angular-promise

I need help on iterating Json through for loop using protractor:

**Context of my issue:**

1. I have a method that returns Json response of REST Service.
2. The response is handled in another method and iterated through for loop. During each iteration the id is passed to xpath of an element in page class (Page object model) where the element is clicked and returns a promise.
3. Code inside the for loop is executed only once successfully and rest of the iterations where the call to page class method is happening but element click inside that page method is not happening.
4. I know something wrong with promise handling through for loop in my code. Searched through many pages and blogs and tried the ways they suggested but couldn't succeed. I am just mentioning below one way of handling promises in loop suggested in one of the blogs.

Help on this is highly appreciated.

here is my test code:

```
    **Method that returns REST Api response:** This method returns rest api response using node fetch.

    getRestApiResponse(resp) {
            let nf = require('node-fetch');
            let clientHierarchyDtos: ClientHierarchyDto[];
            let url = 'some url';

            nf(url)
            .then(function(response) { 
                return response.json();
             }).then(function(data) {
                 resp(data);
            })

        }

      ClientHierarchy class: This is the structure of Json data.

      export class ClientHierarchyDto {

    id: string;
    label: string;
    name: string;
    childLevels: ClientHierarchyDto[];

}

    **Test Method code where this response is iterated:**

    const rqnsCascadeRestServiceObj: rqnsCascadeRestService = new rqnsCascadeRestService();

      let clientHierarchies: ClientHierarchyDto[];
      var promises = [];
      rqnsCascadeRestServiceObj.getRestApiResponse(function (resp) {
        const clientHierarchies = resp;
        console.log("hierarchy size: " + clientHierarchies.length);
        for (let regionLevelHierarchy of clientHierarchies) {
          const rqnsCascadeMeasureDashboardPage: rqnsCascadeMeasureDashboard = new rqnsCascadeMeasureDashboard();
                promises.push(rqnsCascadeMeasureDashboardPage.expandAccordian(regionLevelHierarchy.id));

        }

        Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
          return true;
      }, (error) => {
          return false;

      });
      });

    **Page class method where element click is happening:** This is the method to which ids from json is passed to element locator and clicking the element.

    Accordian:ElementFinder; 
    expandAccordian(Id:string) {
            console.log("accordianId inside: "+ Id);
            this.Accordian = element(by.id(Id));          
            return this.Accordian.click();
        }


    Please let me know if anything else is needed.
```

Comment: "Couldn't paste code"...Hard to help without seeing the code. This question will be closed without it. Please edit your question.

Comment: Added test code.